# pandas dataframe: groupby, apply function returning an array and map back the result

Tags: python, pandas

Let's consider a data frame:

```py
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.random.random(size=10)})
df["y"] = np.where(df.x < 0.5, 0, 1)
```

Output:

```
          x  y
0  0.417022  0
1  0.720324  1
2  0.000114  0
3  0.302333  0
4  0.146756  0
5  0.092339  0
6  0.186260  0
7  0.345561  0
8  0.396767  0
9  0.538817  1
```

I would like to add a new column called `z`:

```
          x  y  z
0  0.417022  0  0
1  0.720324  1  0
2  0.000114  0  1
3  0.302333  0  2
4  0.146756  0  3
5  0.092339  0  4
6  0.186260  0  5
7  0.345561  0  6
8  0.396767  0  7
9  0.538817  1  1
```

I figured out that I can use `apply` function and try to `map` the result, but it doesn't work...

```py
z = df.groupby("y").apply(lambda d: np.arange(d["y"].size))
df["z"] = df["y"].map(z)
```

Output:

```
          x  y                         z
0  0.417022  0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
1  0.720324  1                    [0, 1]
2  0.000114  0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
3  0.302333  0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
4  0.146756  0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
5  0.092339  0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
6  0.186260  0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
7  0.345561  0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
8  0.396767  0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
9  0.538817  1                    [0, 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['z'] = df.groupby('y')['y'].cumcount()
print df
          x  y  z
0  0.417022  0  0
1  0.720324  1  0
2  0.000114  0  1
3  0.302333  0  2
4  0.146756  0  3
5  0.092339  0  4
6  0.186260  0  5
7  0.345561  0  6
8  0.396767  0  7
9  0.538817  1  1
```

More generic solution use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df["z"] = df.groupby("y")['y'].transform(lambda d: np.arange(d.size))
print df
          x  y  z
0  0.417022  0  0
1  0.720324  1  0
2  0.000114  0  1
3  0.302333  0  2
4  0.146756  0  3
5  0.092339  0  4
6  0.186260  0  5
7  0.345561  0  6
8  0.396767  0  7
9  0.538817  1  1
```

Comment: Do you know more generic solution? With `lambda` function?

Comment: sorry, but I think `map` cannot be used here.

Comment: Thank you! I could understand how to solve my problem with `transform`.